# Uploading multiple images on Dropbox from my IOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, dropbox

I am working on an application in which i upload multiple images on Dropbox from my IPhone.
When i upload my images only 5 images uploaded at a time whether i select 5 or more than 5 images.
Below is my code for uploading images on Dropbox::

```
- (void)_startUpload:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        NSLog(@"%@",(NSString*)countere);
    }];
    // while(countere != 0){
    HUD=[[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];

    HUD.labelText=@"Please wait for Uploading";
    HUD.dimBackground=YES;
    [HUD show:YES];

    //NSString *fileString=@"/%@",albumNAME;
    //  NSData * JPEGData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    self.file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",albumNAME];
    NSLog(@"File Name ---> %@",self.file);
    NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 100;
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PicBackMan-%ld.jpg",(long)randomNumber];
    NSArray *pathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                            NSUserDomainMask,
                                                            YES);
    countere--;
    NSString *localPath = [[pathList objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];;
    NSLog(@"local Path ----> %@",localPath);
    NSString *destDir = self.file;
    // [presenter presentHud:@"Uploading"];
    [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                    withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
    //[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    //   }
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(savingDone) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

}
```

on the log i am getting the below error::

2014-06-06 15:51:55.977 PicBackMan_1[3499:60b] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files_put/dropbox/Like-2/PicBackMan-12.jpg - (-1005) Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)" UserInfo=0xa5d4570 {destinationPath=/Like-2/PicBackMan-12.jpg, sourcePath=/Users/bettermac9/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/F51F7F8F-91C5-4E67-90E6-4218941D3A67/Documents/image.jpg}

2014-06-06 15:51:56.500 PicBackMan_1[3499:60b] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/metadata/dropbox/Photos - (404) Path '/Photos' not found

2014-06-06 15:51:56.500 PicBackMan_1[3499:60b] restClient:loadMetadataFailedWithError: The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 404.)

i am not getting why there is connection timeout??
Photos uploaded on Dropbox,some of them not stored properly and image not view error comes.
Please help me out with the better solution.

Thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

Try serializing your uploads instead of trying to do them all at once. For some operations (like uploading a file), Dropbox has to serialize the writes on the server, so even if you start five uploads at once, only one will actually be processed at a time. The more uploads you try to do simultaneously, the more likely it is that the later ones will time out while they're waiting.

Comment: @smaarx: Dear sir, thank you for your kind suggestion.sir can you please tell me that how can i serializing my uploads in IOS application.I am working with IOS application development from last 2 months so i don't know how to do that.so Please let me know.Thank you